# MemFault in GC when calling back a closure from C

Tags: lua, embedded, closures, keil

I working with Keil, MDK-ARM Pro 4.71 for a Cortex-M3 target(STM32F107).

I have compiled the Lua interpreter and a Lua "timer" module that interfaces the chip's timers. I'd like to call a lua function when the timer is elapsed.

Here is a sample use :

```
t = timer.open()
t.event = function() print("Bing !") end
t:start()
```

Until here, everything works fine :-) ! I see the "Bing !" message being printed each time the timer elapses.

Now if I use a closure :

```
t = timer.open()
i = 0
t.event = function() i = i + 1; print(i); end
t:start()
```

I'm having a bad memory access in the GC after some amount of timer's updates. Since it's an embedded context with very few memory, I may be running out of memory quite fast if there is a leak.

Here is the "t.event" setter (ELIB_TIMER is a C structure representing my timer) :

```
static int ElibTimerSetEvent(lua_State* L)
{
   ELIB_TIMER* pTimer_X = ElibCheckTimer(L, 1, TRUE);

   if (pTimer_X->LuaFuncKey_i != LUA_REFNIL)
   {
      luaL_unref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, pTimer_X->LuaFuncKey_i);
      pTimer_X->LuaFuncKey_i = LUA_REFNIL;
   }

   if (!lua_isnil(L, 2))
   {
      pTimer_X->LuaFuncKey_i = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
   }

   return 0;
}
```

And here is the native callback implementation :

```
static void ElibTimerEventHandler(SYSEVT_HANDLE Event_H)
{
   ELIB_TIMER* pTimer_X = (ELIB_TIMER*)SWLIB_SYSEVT_GetSideData(Event_H);
   lua_State* L = pTimer_X->L;
   int i = lua_gettop(L);
   if (pTimer_X->LuaFuncKey_i != LUA_REFNIL)
   {
      lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, pTimer_X->LuaFuncKey_i);
      lua_call(L, 0, 0);
      lua_settop(L, i);
   }
}
```

This is synchronized externally, so this isn't a synchronization issue.

Am I doing something wrong ?

EDIT

Here is the callstack (with a lua_pcall instead of lua_call, but it is the same). The first line is my hard fault handler.

[image: Lua call stack]

Comment: What happens if you leave the call to `print()` out of the event handler? You say it is synchronized externally, but my first hunch is that something is going wrong with that synchronization. The Lua core is not threadsafe if more than one thread makes calls on the same lua_State. I don't spot an obvious problem with your event handler code shown so far, you are storing the lua_State for each event, you are getting the handler from its registry, your call looks rational, so it is something less obvious and more subtle.

Comment: I just noticed that as written, your example is not a closure in the sense that it has private upvalues. As written, it is merely accessing a global named `i`. To have an upvalue, `i` would have to be `local` in the lexical scope where the closure is defined. We know that access to `_G` isn't completely broken in your timer handler because you did successfully call `print`. Now I am even more convinced it is a synchronization issue, and all you've done by adding the arithmetic on `i` is change the size of the timing window.

Comment: Well, in the current case, there is no synchronization at all because it is in a single thread (we're in a testing context). After t:start() is called, the thread just goes waiting for the timer to elapse and calls the callback synchronously. There is no other command that is given to the interpreter. Thanks for pointing out the global nature of i, I'll try with a local i see if it makes a difference.

Comment: Yes, as long as each Lua state is called by exactly one thread, you need not worry about synchronization. It could become an issue when threads need to communicate with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the problem ! I ran out of stack (native stack, not Lua) space :p.
I guess this specific script was causing a particularly long call stack. After increasing the allocated memory for my native stack, the problem is gone. On the opposite, if I reduce it, I can't even initialize the interpreter.

Many thanks to those who tried to help here.

Comment: Ah yes, the joys of guessing required stack requirements. Never easy. I'd add some stack overflow testing to a background thread. Perhaps a simple sentinel cookie in the words just before and just after the stack, and a thread that validates that all stacks still have their cookies (and that the thread's saved SP is in bounds). At least you'll get notice of the overflow sooner...

Comment: Out of curiosity, while diagnosing this issue what finally gave you the hint it was a stack space problem?

Comment: I just guessed and tried changing the allocated heap and stack size

Answer (score 1):

Found a bug in your C code. You broke the lua stack in `static int ElibTimerSetEvent(lua_State* L)`

`luaL_ref` will pop the value on the top of Lua stack: http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#luaL_ref

So you need to copy the value to be refed, before the call to `luaL_ref`:

```
lua_pushvalue(L, 2); // push the callback to stack top, and then it will be consumed by luaL_ref()
```

Please fix this and try again.

Comment: Do you say that I broke the stack because a function isn't supposed to pop its arguments from the stack ? I try that anyway, thanks.

Comment: @Chen I'm not sure that's really an issue here. His `ElibTimerSetEvent` isn't actually returning anything back to lua. Does it matter that `luaL_ref` pops that value off if it's never used again?

Comment: @Chen The only way I can see this being an issue if this function isn't getting called like a lua function, eg. not using `lua_pcall` or `lua_call`. If the calling code from other parts of his program expects the value just popped off by `luaL_ref` to be preserved on the stack on return then this can be a problem.

Comment: Assuming that this was called from Lua, as appears to be the intent, then leaving the stack at a different depth on exit is not a problem. Part of the call process does stack cleanup after popping the return values from the function. A function not called from Lua is a different matter, and should treat the Lua stack with care. The timer event handler is an example of such.